# Completing the square (diagonal matrix/bilinear form)

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & 5 \\ 2 & 1 & 3 \\ 5 & 3 & \frac{17}{2} \end{pmatrix} \in M_3(\mathbb{R})$.

I want to find an invertible matrix $C$ such that $C^TAC=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, since there are three eigenvalues which are postive, negative and zero.

I tried to use completing the square with the bilinear form $s(v,v)=\langle v,Av \rangle$:

$s(v,v)= \langle v,Av \rangle=(v_1,v_2,v_3)\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & 5 \\ 2 & 1 & 3 \\ 5 & 3 & \frac{17}{2}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} v_1\\v_2\\v_3 \end{pmatrix}=2v_1^2+4v_1v_2+10v_1v_3+v_2^2+6v_2v_3+\frac{17}{2}v_3^2$

Now I used completing the square with respect to $v_1$:

$2(v_1^2+2v_1v_2+5v_1v_3)+v_2^2+6v_2v_3+\frac{17}{2}v_3^2$

$=2(v_1^2+v_1(2v_2+5v_3))+v_2^2+6v_2v_3+\frac{17}{2}v_3^2$

$=2(v_1^2+v_1(2v_2+5v_3)+\frac{1}{2}(2v_2+5v_3)^2-\frac{1}{2}(2v_2+5v_3)^2)+v_2^2+6v_2v_3+\frac{17}{2}v_3^2$

$=2(v_1+(2v_2+5v_3))^2-\frac{1}{2}(2v_2+5v_3)^2+v_2^2+6v_2v_3+\frac{17}{2}v_3^2$

$=2(v_1+2v_2+5v_3)^2-\frac{1}{2}(2v_2+5v_3)^2+(v_2+3v_3)^2-\frac{1}{2}v_3^2$

Now there is one summand too much so I can't set a matrix $C$ which is the inverse of the matrix with the entries in the braces.

I think I made a mistake with the completing the square but I don't see where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2x^2+4xy+10xz+y^2+6yz+\frac{17}2z^2=2\left(x+y+\frac52z\right)^2-y^2-4yz-4z^2=$$

$$=2\left(x+y+\frac52z\right)^2-\left(y+2z\right)^2$$

and there you go: one positive, one negative, one zero...

Comment: Is there a formula for this or how can it be seen that $2x^2+4xy+10xz+y^2+6yz+\frac{17}2z^2=2\left(x+y+\frac52z\right)^2-y^2-4yz-4z^2$?

Comment: @Gurterz It is just completing the square: $$ax^2+bx=a\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{2a}$$ If you want to make sure the formular is correct, open up the right side and confirm it equals the left side...

Comment: I get $2(x+\frac{4}{2 \cdot2}y+\frac{10}{2 \cdot 2}z)^2-\frac{4^2}{2 \cdot 2}y-\frac{10^2}{2 \cdot 2}z= 2(x+y+\frac{5}{2}z)^2-4y-25z$ with this formula. Or do I have to use other numbers for it?

Comment: @Gurterz That's not correct, of course: what happened to $\;-y^2\,,\,\frac{17}2z^2\;$ and etc. in the **original expression**??

Comment: Ok, now I get the result, but how did you use the $-\frac{b^2}{2a}$ in this case?

Comment: Observe that here, $\;a=2\;$ and $\;b=4y+10z=\;$ the "coefficient" of $\;x\;$ , so just apply the above formula to complete the square wrt $\;x\;$ first, and in this particular case you are left with a square : $\;-y^2-4yz-4z^2=-(y+2z)^2\;$, but if not then you complete the square wrt $\;y\;$ and etc.

Answer (score 1):

I doubled your matrix to get all integers:

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 4 & 10 \\ 
4 & 2 & 6 \\ 
10 & 6 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Divide back by 2, you have diagonal matrix with diagonal $2, -1,0.$ So, as a final step, multiply on the far left and far right by
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) \; , \;
$$
which is its own transpose.

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 4 & 10 \\ 
4 & 2 & 6 \\ 
10 & 6 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 4 & 10 \\ 
4 & 2 & 6 \\ 
10 & 6 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 10 \\ 
0 &  - 2 &  - 4 \\ 
10 &  - 4 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 &  - 4 \\ 
0 &  - 4 &  - 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 4 & 10 \\ 
4 & 2 & 6 \\ 
10 & 6 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 4 & 10 \\ 
4 & 2 & 6 \\ 
10 & 6 & 17 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: How did you find the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$?